# Unable to connect to a Local DB (mdf) from C# form application

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, database

I tried to play with Database creation and queries. In order to do that I started a C# form application, added a Database Service then added a Table with some values, then I wanted to use some code to retrieve those values. 
Here's the code:

```
string conn = "data source = ./SQLEXPRESS; AttachDbFilename=C:\\Users\\Asus\\Desktop\\RobaMia\\SQLSERVER\\WindowsFormsApplication3\\WindowsFormsApplication3\\Database1.mdf; Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True";

SqlConnection sql = new SqlConnection(conn);

sql.Open();
MessageBox.Show("Connection Opened");
sql.Close();
```

Sadly the program throws an exception when comes to the open because it seems it cannot find the Database...

"Server not found or not accessible"

I don't know what is the problem, what would you suggest?

---

Ok, it seems to work now but I get an incorrect syntax for my query

string conn = "Server=(LocalDB)\v11.0; AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Asus\Desktop\RobaMia\SQLSERVER\WindowsFormsApplication3\WindowsFormsApplication3\Database1.mdf; Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=False";

```
        string queryString = "SELECT * FROM Table";
        SqlConnection sql = new SqlConnection(conn);

        sql.Open();
        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(queryString, sql);

      /* --->here I get the error*/ command.ExecuteNonQuery();

        DataSet data = new DataSet();
        adapter.Fill(data);
        MessageBox.Show(data.ToString());
        sql.Close();
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the data source part your connection string is wrong. It should be:

```
"Data source=.\\SQLEXpress"
```

Complete:

```
string conn = "Data source=.\\SQLEXpress; AttachDbFilename=C:\\Users\\Asus\\Desktop\\RobaMia\\SQLSERVER\\WindowsFormsApplication3\\WindowsFormsApplication3\\Database1.mdf; Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True";
```

https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/

As an additional note, you may be best off placing this in an `app.config` or `web.config` file just encase you reference the connection string multiple times and later you decide to change the value of it.

Comment: @DarrenDavies Well time to clean up this chat and GTFO! :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried(LocalDB), instead of SQLExpress?

```
"Server=(localdb)\\Test;Integrated Security=true;AttachDbFileName= myDbFile;"
```

http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/creating-a-connection-string